# Shell script returning incorrect output

Tags: shell

I am trying to print the multiplication table from 1 to 10 in shell. However, my output is only printing it for 1.

My current implementation is

```sh
i=1
j=1
while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
  while [ $j -le 10 ]
  do
    echo " $i x $j = `expr $i \* $j`"
    j=`expr $j + 1`
  done
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: You need to reinitialize `j` to zero before you start the inner `while` loop.

Comment: but i have already initialized it.

Comment: I said **reinitialize**.  It means (literally) "initialize again".  (I recommend that you learn about and apply the ["Rubber Duck" debugging technique](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the initialization of `j` inside the while loop. After completion of the first loop, your variable `j` has the value as `10`. So for the second iteration of the outer loop, it's not entering the inner loop since it's value is `10`.

```sh
i=1
while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
  j=1
  while [ $j -le 10 ]
  do
    echo " $i x $j = `expr $i \* $j`"
    j=`expr $j + 1`
  done
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```